# pom.xml - Content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: xml, spring, maven, pom.xml

In my spring project, I have added a new dependency in pom.xml with Eclipse EE. After building, am getting an error at the last line of pom.xml file which tells that **Content is not allowed in trailing section**. Have attached the error screenshot below.

[image]

This error persists even after cleaning the project. How to fix this?

Comment: Please add the whole POM as text.

Comment: Is the maven build is working in the terminal/command prompt?